# Show answers which are answered in bounty period

Tags: feature-request, answers, bounties, participation

I had answered many questions in bounty period on SO. It's not the thing that you always get bounty. But I would like to see competing and good answers. So that I can understand from those answers (in future also). But whenever I want to check answers which are answered in bounty period, it's very hard. (Many of my friends also had this problem. )

There are already 3 tabs `active`, `offered` and `earned` in bounties tab. It will be great to have one more tab `participated`. In which showing answers which are answered in bounty period.

[image: rep description]

1. Should there be one more tab `participated` in bounties tab or not?
2. What are it's disadvantages if feature given?

Comment: Those answers would be listed in [your list of answers](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1045444/somnath-muluk?tab=answers).

Comment: Yes I know those answers are enlisted in answers tab. But it is very hard to check which answers are answered in bounty period. Earned bounty answers are also listed in answers tab. But it is easy to find earned bounties by earned tab. It is innocent request to have participated tab nothing personal reason behind this.

Answer (score 1):

> But it is very hard to check which answers are answered in bounty period.

You can sort the answers on a question by time, so it's actually very easy to check that...

[image]

Comment: I am saying about my answers, in my profile. And to check answers which are answered 1-2 months before and answered in bounty period.

Comment: Why would that be any useful and/or applicable to everyone? :S