# Display bounty symbol on the Answers tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Show answers which are answered in bounty period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123735/show-answers-which-are-answered-in-bounty-period)

A few days ago I answered a question that had a bounty and today I remembered something valuable that I wanted to add to my answer.

The problem was that I didn't remember the exact title of the question and finding it again took some time. As the bounty period hasn't expired, I couldn't find an easy way to list the answers that I had given that were still candidates for bounties.

Is there a way to quickly identify the answers I've given that are still competing for (active) bounties?

If not, maybe we should start thinking on how to do that. My initial suggestion is that we add the bounty symbol before the title of the question in the *answers tab*.

The image below shows what it could look like:

[image]

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Not only the problem remains, but the user who posted an answer seemed to misunderstand what was being asked. Plus, I offer a simple solution to the problem, so I don't think it can be considered an exact duplicate.

Comment: For those of you wandering, the **Bounties (tab) > Active** only displays the bounties you offered, and not the ones you are competing for. Maybe this feature could be improved as an alternative solution to what I proposed.